# Cross browser inconsistencies with margins?

Tags: html, css, webkit, textarea, gecko

I'm having a small problem with x-browser compatibility (Chrome and FF) for a textarea and margins.

The page in question is here: http://www.mylesgray.com/contact/

The `textarea` under "Message" as you can see is different in FF than in Chrome:

FF 11:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome 17:

[image: Chrome]

You can see if you look at the bottom and right hand edges of both Chrome lines up perfectly but FF seems further in both directions and I cannot work out why either in Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools.

It seems to be a webkit vs gecko problem as Espresso shows the same as Chrome.

The CSS for the above is:

```
.wpcf7-message {
    float: left;
    width: 26em;
    height: 12.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.wpcf7-message textarea {
    resize: none;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 1.1em;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Myles

Comment: You could try box-sizing: border-box on the textarea. I'm not sure it would work but it's worth a try.

Comment: my guess is that it's the `em` units you're using everywhere.  Webkit renders text slightly differently then gecko (same text will be different widths in both browsers).  As a test, set all padding, margins and widths to absolute values and see if the inconsistency still exists.

Comment: Surely it would be all relational anyway? I've tried that and yep it worked perfectly but mixing units like em and px makes me feel dirty, using absolute values like px makes me feel dirty anyway. Is there any way to achieve this with em? - I'm guessing not?

Comment: @Pat If you create an answer I will upvote and mark yours as the answer as it was the closest to what got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely the `em` units you're using everywhere for widths, margins and padding.  The `em` unit is based on font size and webkit renders fonts slightly differently than gecko (the same text in webkit and gecko will be different widths).

As a test, change your CSS widths, padding and margins to absolute `px` values and check if this fixes the inconsistencies.

Answer (score -1):

I would say

Use [blueprint css framework](http://blueprintcss.org/), this will help you these type of Cross browser problems and save much times

it is come with IE fixed files,

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Already using Eric Mayer's CSS Reset - no need for any frameworks. Thanks though.